# Class that handles header and footer includes looks like a mess

Tags: php, object-oriented, html, php5

I tried making a class that handles my header and footer of my site. It looks like a mess, because I like to preserve the indentations as is.

But I'm wondering if there maybe is an even cleaner or better way of writing this class?

```
<?php
class HeadFoot {
    protected $title,
              $scripts;

    public function __construct($title, $scripts) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->scripts = $scripts;
    }

    public function getHeader() {
        if($this->title) {
$header = <<< EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>$this->title - Domain</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/init.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/layout.css">

EOD;

if($this->scripts) {
    foreach($this->scripts as $script) {
        $header .= str_repeat(' ', 8) . $script . "\n";
    }
}

$header .= <<< EOD
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topbar"></div>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <h1 id="site-name"><a href="/">Domain</a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>


EOD;

$header .= Navigation::get();
$header .= str_repeat(' ', 12) . "\n";

            return $header;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getFooter($ads = null) {
        if($ads) {
            return
'            <div id="footer">
                <p>Copyright © 2014 - Domain.net</p>
                <p><a href="#" title="Terms of Service">Terms of Service</a> / <a href="#" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>';
        }

        return
'            <div id="advertisement">
                <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                     style="display: inline-block; width: 468px; height: 60px; vertical-align: top;"
                     data-ad-client="ca-pub-8849502800889803"
                     data-ad-slot="2598909127"></ins>
                <script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <p>Copyright © 2014 - Domain.net</p>
                <p><a href="#" title="Terms of Service">Terms of Service</a> / <a href="#" title="Privacy Policy">Privacy Policy</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Separation of Concerns

You should implement [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). In your case, don't mix logic with your view. Follow basic MVC, where M (model) is the data source, V (view) is where your HTML is, and C (controller), where all your logic is. In this case, put your HTML in one file, the logic in the other.

## Templating

One thing that messes up development is when logic is mixed to the template. It makes the template messy and hard to maintain and visualize. I suggest you take a look at the [PHP implementation of Mustache templates](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php). In your controller, simply make a function that loads the template to a variable, feeds it to Mustache, put some data in and done.

## Inheritance

One use of inheritance is to hide utility functions. For instance, you can create a View class, where your future views inherit from.

## End Result

You can simply do something as simple as this in the controller!

```
public function index(){
    $myView = new View('path/to/template');     // Create a view
    $myDataSource = new Model('MODEL_NAME');    // Create a model
    $theData = myDataSource->getData();         // Grab data
    $theResultHTML = myView->render($theData);  // Render data to template and print
}
```